# how to disable camera function in android programatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to disable camera in my android application pragmatically
here i want to make an application in which once i start the application there is two button in start and stop in one when i click on the start button my application will go to home screen and will disable the camera function completely even on clicking on the camera icon in my application it wont enable and also by not clicking the hardware button unless until i again go back to my application and click on the stop button which will also go back to the home screen and this time my camera function of my phone will work properly

please help me out
thanx's in advance

Comment: I very much doubt that this is possible. Perhaps you're app could "allocate" the camera and never release it, but that's only a guess.

Comment: Look Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10945442/614807

Comment: but is there any solution that will be help full to me to achive this

Answer (score 1):

```
private CheckBoxPreference mDisableCameraCheckbox;
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
...
mDPM.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminSample, mDisableCameraCheckbox.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can not disable camera in your regular application.but it is possible to disable using admin setting in ICS and higher versions..check it here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: but how can i do it directly through my application that i want to make with out using Device policy manager

Comment: read the whole description on above link.there is an example which shows how to use Admin settings.check it properly.