# Can I still use Device Admin API only to disable the CAMERA for android 11 and above as Device Admin API is deprecated

Tags: android, device-admin

In my project I’m using Device Admin API for disabling the CAMERA. It is working fine in Android 7 and 8.  Can I still use Device Admin API only to disable the CAMERA for android 11 and above as Device Admin API is deprecated.

It is working fine in Android 7 and 8. Will it work for Android 10, 11 and above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Disable camera will not work for devices after Android 10.0. It is stated in google docs that it will throw a security exception. Check this link for reference.

https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation#deprecated_policies

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation says:

> Starting with the release of Android 10.0, the above-mentioned policies will throw a SecurityException when invoked by a device admin on apps targeting API level 29.

So you might be able to make it continue to work by setting your API level to 28 or less.

Related: [How to disable camera in android 12 AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619160/how-to-disable-camera-in-android-12-aosp), [Android: Enable/Disable Camera programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944562/android-enable-disable-camera-programmatically), [how to disable camera function in android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697816/how-to-disable-camera-function-in-android-programatically)